# error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt - even after changing the settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker-errors, coff

I have a C++ windows forms project built using MS Visual Studio 2010. I get the following error when I execute it.
  error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

I know it's a common problem discussed in many forums. I tried the solution as well, which is setting

Project Properties -> Configuration Properties - > Linker -> General -> Enable Incremental Linking -> No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)

But I still have the same issue.

anyone knows why it is ?

Comment: Did you install VS2010 SP1?

Comment: No. I didn't. should I ?

Comment: Yes. It certainly won't hurt...